# Adding a fragment on top of another fragment onClickListener issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm **adding** a fragment to an activity instead of **replacing** the current fragment (because this corresponds to the type of behavior I want to have).

My problem is that clicking in a spot on the top fragment (the one that's currently visible), where a view in the non-visible fragment is located, causes an onClick event on the view in the second, non-visible fragment, to fire.
Why is this happening and how can I prevent this?

This is the code I use to first add the ListView fragment to the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        listFragment = new ListFragment ();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frame_container, listFragment)
                .addToBackStack(listFragment .TAG)
                .commit();
    }

    ...

}
```

In this same activity I'm adding the second fragment, on top of the list fragment:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    ...
            createItemFragment = new CreateItemFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.frame_container, createItemFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(createItemFragment.TAG)
                    .commit();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Stacking up fragments like this isn't really a good idea. Why do you need to do it?

Comment: I've mentioned the reason in my responses below.

Comment: The things is that your problems don't require that the fragment stays in the view hierarchy. You can save/restore the scroll position by properly using the bundle. You can cache data locally to avoid fetching the images too frequently. This is StackOverflow, so you'll find someone who will give you an "answer" that helps you do this, but it's just bad practice. If a fragment isn't visible, it needs to release its resources. Failing to do so makes you a bad citizen on the user's device and a top candidate for being closed by the OS scheduler as soon as your app goes to the background.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can just add the following attribute to the XML root layout of the fragment that agoes on top-

```
android:clickable="true"
```

This will ensure that touch events will not propagate further than the top layer.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the "proper" solution to my problem, but this did in fact work, and was also super easy to implement so that's what I went with. Thanks!

Comment: well why isnt this a proper solution? This essentially tells the system that click events should not propagate further than the top layer - that seems proper to me if you are overlaying views with active event listners.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I just wouldn't have thought I could use this property this way. Thanks again!

Comment: To the downvoter- care to comment? what can be improved/made better about the answer?

Comment: That's a very good solution. You might also want to call getView().clearFocus() before pushing the new fragment to make sure there's nothing focused so that no cursor will be shown on top of the new fragment.

Comment: weird, I would have thought that this was default operation

Answer (score 2):

If you're adding a fragment it'll overlap all the fragments under it So if you want to display both views at the same time this is the way to do it. Naturally with both view present both will listen for touch events. If you want to preserve the fragment but not show it use:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
ft.detach(fragment).commit();
```

That will remove the fragments view without destroying the fragment.

you can call

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
ft.attach(fragment).commit();
```

later to reattach it to the view.

alternatively you could just change your on click listener to

```
public void onClick (View v){
    if(!v.isShown()){
        return;
    }
    //Stuff the listener should do.
}
```

Comment: Can't get these solutions to work for me. Can't use the detach option because I don't know which fragment is going to be the one I'm adding on top of. Tried the v.isShown() but it's returning true even after adding the second fragment on top and not being actually visible.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, I _do_ need the fragment to overlap the one below it. I just want to prevent the fragment below of being "actionable". Meaning, I want to prevent any interaction with it while the second, visible fragment, is visible.

Comment: What kind of view are you using that has the listener? you could use `view.setEnabled(false)` on the view of the bottom fragment to disable it. then you could replace `!v.isShown()` with `v.isEnabled()`.

Comment: The "below" view is a ListView. I add a different fragment on top of it and when I click on an empty space in the visible fragment, I basically trigger a onItemClick event for an item in the ListView.

Comment: Did you nest the listviews adapter in your fragment class? Providing some code would help me come up with a specific answer.

Comment: No, its adapter is in a separate class and file.

Comment: I suggest putting a setter on your adapter then that you delegate trough to your fragment. That setter would contain a boolean to disable your listeners and could be called by your activity when you do fragment transactions.

Comment: Added a bit of code to the post. Pretty standard, so not sure how much it helps.

Comment: Setting a flag in the adapter seems like a hack to me. The reason I don't wanna _replace_ my ListView fragment is that I don't wanna lose the state (position) the user was in when he left the fragment and then came back. I've seen this behavior in many other apps, where you navigate from a list fragment to another one, then go back to the same list fragment, at the same spot. I'm sure I'm not the first one to try to implement this.

Comment: Thats why I recommended using the detach and attach methods. Those should be able to preserve the state of the fragment and it's list view. you could also just save the current position of the list view in your fragment `onSaveInstanceState()` and use `setSelection()` to restore it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)

Comment: There's more than one type of fragment that could be added on top of the ListView fragment. To use this approach I'll need to know what's the current visible fragment. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Also, I prefer not to go with the onSaveInstanceState() + setSelection() approach because I load a bunch of images in my ListView from a remote server so if I'll have to create a new ListView fragment, that would mean sending a new request to the server, which I would want to prevent.

Comment: Save your fragments in an array list and have an int variable point to  the one you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

well,I think the best way is **set onClickListener  to the locateView which you click** on the top-fragment .
if you use the way **android:clickable="true" answered by The Metal Beard**, and also you set any ImageView's **selector** states (see below), then you will find the bug : if you click the other space place ,the imageView will **change** the status.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mCollect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/specialprice_collect_selector" />
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/specialprice_collect_p" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/specialprice_collect_n"/>
</selector>
```

if the clicked View on top-fragment is mBootomLayout,just do it like this:

```
mBootomLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: did not understand your solution.. can you tell more info about setOnClickListener ? where I need to set click listener? Thank you)

Answer (score 0):

```
I had also faced a similar issue. I have solved it by applying setOnClickListener to each view separately. 
Below example:
 binding.tvSchedule.setOnClickListener{
                openSchedule()
            }
    
**Note**: Do not implement View.OnClickListener to your fragment Class.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is not too late. I believed it might still be helpful.

What you should do is to get the root view of the fragment, call it `setOnTouchListener`, implement the `View.OnTouchListener` and return true in it `onTouch` method