# Prevent clicks from going to the fragment beneath?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have just one Activity in my app that hosts fragments that are dynamically changed using a transaction. At the start the user is required to select a show and on click a new fragment is loaded which shows the list of episodes of that show along with a video player.

There is some margin between the video player and the list.

Now, here is an issue. Whenever I click on the little space between the video player and the list of episodes, the click is sent to the fragment below.

**How do I prevent this?**

Just to help you visualize, on clicking on a show, the user is shown a dialog box that tells a little bit about that show and how many seasons it has, along with a button "Watch The Show". When I click on the space between the video player and the list, the dialog box pops up as though I clicked on a show.

Comment: **"Just to help you visualize.."** : A better way for us to visualize things would be if you showed some actual code. In particular anything relayed to touch/click event listeners.

Comment: @Squonk It would become very messy. The shows fragment has an interface that relays the click to the activity when the user clicks "Watch The Show". Tell me a not-so-messy way to post the code :)

Comment: This seams to be a similar question with a ver good answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764980/adding-a-fragment-on-top-of-another-fragment-onclicklistener-issue/24765373#24765373. The one above mine.